# NSOpenPanel to choose files and populate a NSTableView

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nstableview, nsopenpanel

I was wondering how can I populate a NSTableView by first getting files through NSOpenPanel. It's like listing/displaying the files after I choose from my folders at runtime.

EDIT: So i have this kind of working (through binding).... however i can't get it to display unless i click at the top of the table. And if you open to get more files the display won't update again at all.

I feel like this maybe be because the controllerArray's Received Action add: is not linked.
The code below is what I have now

```
@IBAction func openPanel(sender: NSButton) {
    let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["pdf"]
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
    openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
    openPanel.beginWithCompletionHandler { (result) -> Void in

        if result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
            var url:NSURL = openPanel.URL!
            var pdfFile: PDFModel = PDFModel()
            pdfFile.initWithURL(url)
            self.insertFileLibrary(pdfFile, inFileListAtIndex: self.fileLibrary.count)

        }
    }
}


func insertFileLibrary(pdfModel:PDFModel, inFileListAtIndex index:Int){
    fileLibrary.insertObject(pdfModel, atIndex: index)       
}

func removeObjectFromFileLibraryAtIndex(index:Int){
        fileLibrary.removeObjectAtIndex(index)
    }
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in addToTable, are fileList, table and doc what you expect?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow....

Answer (score 0):

Bindings use KVO, you have to mutate fileLibrary in a KVO way surrounded by willChange… and didChange…. It is easier to let NSArrayContoller do this. You can use the addObject(s), insertObject(s) and removeObject(s) methods of NSArrayController.